# Morphism of a k-algebra obtained from Noether's normalization lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm asked to find an injective finite morphism of the following k-algebra.

$A = \frac{K[x, y]}{<y^n - p(x)>}$ where $p(x)\in{k[x]}$.

I'm asked to do so using the following version of Noether's normalization lemma:

Let $A$ be a finitely generated algebra over a field $K$. Then there exists integer $d\geq{0}$ and a finite injective homomorphism $K[T_1,..., T_d]\rightarrow{A}$.

I'm new to the algebraic geometry and have taken the course only with a knowledge of basic abstract algebra, and I don't know how to use the theorem to obtain what is wanted. Obviously I don't want the answer, I just want to know what should I read before attempting to solve this, and just a  clue about how to approach the problem.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Noether's normalization for this.

Let $\rho$ be the composition $K[x]\hookrightarrow K[x,y]\rightarrow A$.

It's easy to see $\rho$ is injective as $\langle y^n-p(x)\rangle\cap K[x]=\{0\}$.

$\rho$ is also finite: indeed, $A$ is generated by $1, \overline{y}, \overline{y^2}, \cdots, \overline{y^{n-1}}$ as a $K[x]$-module.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. The problem explicitely say that we do this using the lemma.

Comment: That made no sense to me. The lemma explains such a morphism exists, but doesn't say how to construct one. Unless it's about to produce the morphism following a possible constructive proof.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Maybe I'm wrong about the whole thing. Thank you again.